# Why my app get different expiration time of Facebook access token?

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token

I have a web application, which needs user's Facebook permissions, and perform some actions in the background. For most users, this app can get an access token with 2 months expiration time through oAuth process. But today I found it gets only one day expiration time access token from a few people.

Since the application is still under development, and testers are all my colleagues. So, I checked their Facebook permission settings, but I didn't find something particular which will affect the expiration time I get from oAuth. So, is there any possible reason why some people can get a longer expiration time, but some other people will only get a shorter one?

Comment: What type of authentication flow are you using? Server side? Client side, do you try to extend the expiration time? And, do all users, under all scenarios go through the exact same authentication flow?

Comment: It is server side authentication and all users under any scenario go through the exact same authentication flow.

Comment: If you get the token by exchanging the "code" then it should return a token for 60 days, if you're using the token from the signed request it probably will have a few hours (one day is a possibility). Are you sure you obtain the access token by exchanging the code for all users?

Comment: I removed that app from user's facebook, and force him to ran through the entire authentication process again (to exchange the "code".) Then everything went fine like what you said, I can get the expiration time with 60 days.

Comment: This issue is no longer reproducible with that user account. But I still don't know why I got that issue before.

Comment: Maybe there was a problem in the authentication flow of that user which resulted in some unexpected behavior. I can't say for sure why what you describe happened.